# Python socket receiving information in a weird way

Tags: python, sockets, tkinter, server

I'm making a simple python chatroom type server, and I am trying to implement server commands. Sending and receiving messages work fine but for some reason when I send a server command It gets received weird. I assume it's how the message is being sent that's causing it to act weird because the server sends server commands separately from how it sends regular messages. Here are the snippets that I think are the problem:
SERVER SIDE:

```py
userData = "server".encode("utf-8")
userHeader = f"{len(userData):<{HEADER_LENGTH}}".encode("utf-8")
print(userHeader)

command = str(command)

messageData = f"cmd${command}".encode("utf-8")
messageHeader = f"{len(command):< {HEADER_LENGTH}}".encode("utf-8")


for client_socket in self.clients:
    client_socket.send(userHeader + userData + messageHeader + messageData)
    window.logData(f"sent server command {command}")
    window.logChat("SERVER",command)
```

This gets called when a button is pressed and then some input is passed in as the command

Here's how the client receives data:

```py
while True:
    try:

            username_header = self.client_socket.recv(HEADER_LENGTH)
            if(not len(username_header)):
                print("connection closed by server")
                sys.exit()
            print(username_header.decode("utf-8").strip())
            username_length = int(username_header.decode("utf-8").strip())

            username = self.client_socket.recv(username_lenght).decode("utf-8")

            message_header = self.client_socket.recv(HEADER_LENGTH)
            message_length = int(message_header.decode("utf-8").strip())
            messageRaw = self.client_socket.recv(message_length).decode("utf-8")

            type_, message = messageRaw.split("$")

            if(type_ == "message"):
                GUI.outgoing.insert(END, "")
                GUI.incoming.insert(END, f"{username} >> {message}")
            elif(type_ == "cmd"):
                if(username == "sever"):
                    print("recieved server command")

    except IOError as e:
        if(e.errno != errno.EAGAIN and e.errno != errno.EWOULDBLOCK):
            print("READ ERR",str(e))
            sys.exit()
        continue
```

I'm not getting any errors on the server side but I am on the client side so here's the output:

```
6
TEST
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kali/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/home/kali/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "client.py", line 119, in main
    username_lenght = int(username_header.decode("utf-8").strip())
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'TEST'
```

I'm sending the text "TEST" to see if the server is receiving data, where it prints the length of the username header it prints 6 which is the length "SERVER" but it also prints "TEST" which is where everything goes wrong.

If you want to play around with the code the github page is https://github.com/snakebite-382/Chatty.py/tree/unstable make sure you download the scripts from the unstable branch. The stable branch has the first release which doesn't have a GUI or the ability to send server commands.

Comment: I'm not sure what the actual problem is, but you probably don't want to send the lengths as a string. Use `struct.pack("H", len(userData))` to send the length as a pair of bytes instead.

Comment: Agree with @chepner encoding length in a fixed amount of bytes is the way to go.
Decide the max length that you want to support and choose the right packing format. If you use `struct.pack` at the transmitting side you have of course to call `struct.unpack` at the receiving side. You can read about struct in the python documentation. https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/struct.html

Comment: `messageHeader = f"{len(command):< {HEADER_LENGTH}}".encode("utf-8")` should be `messageHeader = f"{len(messageData):< {HEADER_LENGTH}}".encode("utf-8")`.

Comment: TCP doesn’t guarantee that (say) 23 bytes sent in one call at the sender is received in a single 23-byte receive at the other end. Does your client code allow fo the possibility that the message sent may not be received in a single event? You need to accumulate received data until enough data for a single message has been received, and process that message without throwing away any extra but using that to add subsequent received data to. The reason most of the internet RFC protocols use carriage-return to terminate a command is to make it easier to detect when a command has been received.

Comment: @chepner @gelonida I'll look into `struck.pack` and see if it makes more sense. @barny I receive data by receiving the length of the header and then reading based on what the header says the length is so I receive exactly how much data I need. @acw1668 I'll try that

Comment: Could further explain why `struck.pack` might be a better option?

Comment: If nothing else, it's more efficient: 2 bytes lets you represent a length up to 65535, as opposed to a length up to 99.

Comment: For that matter: don't send strings like `"message"` and `"cmd"` over the network where a single byte will do. Communication protocols don't have to be human-readable.

Comment: Be aware of the endian used when using `struct.pack()` and `struct.unpack()`.  They must be the same.